# jQuery datepicker stopped working a few days ago...

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

not sure what's going on here and I need a fresh perspective.  I have the jquery plugin datepicker running on hundreds of sites, and it recently stopped working for me.  A few examples:

http://www.arborpointeapartments.com/
http://www.madisonparkapartments.net/

Within the last few days the datepicker just stopped "popping up" when you click in the field.  No idea why.  Nothing has changed on any of the websites and they all load the datepicker files locally.

Assuming that NOTHING has changed at all on the hosting site, how could the datepicker just stop working?

Comment: Chrome is showing an error on line 1416 of `datepicker.js` that "property 'msie' of undefined"

Comment: You include jQuery twice on your site. Version `1.8.3` (hosted on site) and version `1.9.0` (latest version from Google). Removing the latest might help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Danny, you pointed me in the right direction.  I commented out the inclusion of jQuery 1.9.0 and that fixed it.  Looks like the version of datepicker I'm using dies with 1.9.0 version of jQuery.  It works fine when I use jQuery 1.8.3

Guess this is one time where it's not a good idea to load the latest jQuery from Google like this: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js